# Azure web job singleton function is locked

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-storage, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

I am using Azure web job to run some logic continuously.  The function is a singleton function. However, I am getting "Waiting for lock" message after I tried to run this function after a restart of the web app. Does it mean that another instance of the same function is keeping the lock? How can I resolve this?

The function:

```
namespace Ns 
{

    public class Functions
    {
        [Singleton]
        [NoAutomaticTriggerAttribute]
        public static async Task ProcessMethod()
        {
           while(true){
           //process logic here
           await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));}
        }

    }
}
```

The main program:

```
namespace ns
{   
    class Program
    {      
        static void Main()
        {               
            var host = new JobHost();
            host.RunAndBlock();             
        }
    }
}
```

The message that I got:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Singleton attribute description](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Singleton) the lock is adquired during function execution by a Blob lease.

> If another function instance is triggered while this function is
>   running it will wait for the lock, periodically polling for it.

If you have more than one instance of your App Service Plan, this means that there are more than one Webjob and thus the Dashboard might be showing the locked status of the other Webjobs while one is running.

You can [view the blob lease locks](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Singleton#viewing-lease-blobs) that are created on your storage account.

Another option is to try [Listener Singletons](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Singleton#listener-locks) but I never tried it with Manual triggers.

Comment: Is it possible to stop all instances of the same web job? Also when I deploy the web application, do the accompanying web jobs get deployed automatically? Thanks!

Comment: Also, even if I can view it, how i gain the lock for the right function? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by the "right" function? The lock and Singleton is designed so one instance of the function is running, the other instances of that same function are locked out. It's used to define functions that you want to restrict scaling to. The amount of webjob instances is equal to the amount of instances of the App Service Plan you are running it in.

Comment: Web Apps and Web Jobs get deployed automatically if both are present on the same repo and you created the [required configuration file](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-deploy-webjobs/#webjobslist).

Answer (score 0):

I disabled the production function in Azure and set the listenerlockPeriod to 15 seconds as described above.

This lessened the locking behavior significantly.